# Use HERE file and redirect output of command

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have the following code in a batch script:

```
mpirun -np 6 ./laplace <<END
100
100
100
0.01
100
3
2
1
END
| tail -n 1 > output
```

But it isn't working. What I want it to do is to use the HERE file as input to the mpirun command, and then pipe the output to the tail command. However, I think the HERE file and tail output things are getting confused.

How should I write this so that it does what I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you've written in the first line looks like a complete command (a “(compound) list” in shell terminology), so the shell treats it as a complete command. Since there's a here-document start marker (`<<END`), the shell then reads the here-document contents, and then starts a new command. If you want to put the here-document in the middle of a list, you need to indicate to the shell that the list is not finished. Here are couple of ways.

```
mpirun -np 6 ./laplace <<END |
…
END
tail -n 1 > output
```

```
{ mpirun -np 6 ./laplace <<END
…
END
} | tail -n 1 > output
```

Or, of course, you can make sure the command completely fits in the first line.

```
mpirun -np 6 ./laplace <<END | tail -n 1 > output
…
END
```

The rule to remember is that the here-document contents starts after the first unquoted newline after the `<<END` indicator. For example, here's another obfuscated way of writing this script:

```
mpirun -np 6 ./laplace <<END \
| tail -n $(
…
END
             echo 1) > output
```

Comment: That last one! *"obfuscated"*.. You're not kidding! :) .. I had stumbled across the hard-newline idea, but to actually bisect a bracketed block like that is verging on the bizzare.. Is this by design, or is it a coincidental abberation?. (eg. is there a real use for this? ... and you can actually even put multiple semi-colon seperated commands in that first "soft" line..

Comment: @fred: Just a coincidental aberration. There has to be some rule as to where the heredoc starts and stops. Here the rule is that the heredoc is like a single token attached to the next newline token after the `<<END` bit. A backslash-newline nullifies the newline.

Answer (score 7):

```
mpirun -np 6 ./laplace <<END | tail -n 1 > output
100
100
100
0.01
100
3
2
1
END
```