# How to combine Bash's read with HERE-document when shopt -os errexit is in place?

Tags: bash, variable, here-document, read, shopt

I am trying to make use of the solution presented in one of the answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash

In Bash version 4.2.47(1)-release when I execute the following code it prematurely exits because `read` fails when it encounters EOF:

```
shopt -os errexit

function foobar {
    local desc=
    read -d '' -r desc <<EOF
bla bla
EOF
    echo "$desc"
}
```

In order to return success if `read` fails at EOF I have rewritten the line as `read -d '' -r desc || true <<EOF` but now the script indefinitely waits.

Do you know how to make this code work?

Comment: `desc=$(cat <<HERE\nbla bla\nHERE\n)` or `desc='\nbla bla\n '`

Comment: An external command such as `cat` is always an alternative but I prefer to use Bash built-in's wherever possible. Also inserting `\n` at the end of each line is not an option for me since my actual text is around 50 lines long.

Comment: I only did that for the sake of the comments - because otherwise you can't tell. If you want you could just do: `desc= ; : <<HERE\n${desc:=\nbla bla\n}\nHERE\n` Each `\n` should stand in for an actual `\n`ewline character. I think you'll find, though, that many of `bash`isms probably call on `cat` and similar anyway. The one invocation to declare a single 50 line var should not be taxing in anyway. I also think this works in bash, but I'm not sure: `desc=$(<<HERE\n...\nHERE\n)`

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13272/9537. What you want is `read ... <<EOF || true` not `read ... || true <<EOF`. The `<<EOF` is for the `read` not the `true`. I assume your actual code is a bit more complex than your toy example, because in this case assigning to the variable directly would be much simpler.

Comment: @jw013 - the contents of the `<<HEREDOCUMENT` must be read in the first place in order for it to exist at all. Why not just set the variable as a consequence of that action rather using two actions - and calling the external `true` application besides? At the very least OP should use `|| :` instead - at least it is guaranteed as a builtin.

Comment: @mikeserv Did you confuse me with OP? I am not the one that asked the question. Ask OP, not me. Note that your question is something I already pointed out to the OP in my first comment: *"I assume your actual code is a bit more complex than your toy example, because in this case assigning to the variable directly would be much simpler."*, i.e. `desc='bla bla'`.

Comment: @jw013 - I'm sorry. I missed that. My apologies - really.